# How do i transfer erc20 token from another contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethereumjs

I'm creating a contract which will transfer usdt token from users wallet to contract address

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Contract {

    IERC20 public token;
    address public owner;


    constructor(IERC20 _token) {
        token = _token;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external  {
        token.approve(spender, amount);
    }

    // Other important functions.
    function transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external {
        token.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
    }


}
```

Im setting up the usdt contract address in constructor while deploying my contract. The approve funtion is working but when i try to call transfer function its showing maximum allovance exceeded.
My primary motive is that i need to create a mint function in mycontract which will take fee as usdt?

Answer (score 1):

The `token.approve` in this case should not be called from the contract as the `msg.sender` will be the contract instead of the user. In this case, if you like to have a contract to `transferFrom` your token from a `from` address to a `to` address, then you will need to first.

1. Call the `approve` function from the ERC20 token directly from your wallet. This way the `msg.sender` will be your wallet address and the `spender` should be your contract address here.
2. Call the `transfer` function that you already defined here. If you have successfully executed `approve` on the contract with the contract specified as the `spender`, then the execution should be no problem. Just make sure that the `amount` approved is more than what is going to be inputted in `transfer`.

Hope this helps~