# Getting inner ERC20 functions data from outer ERC20 deployments

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapps

I know the title sounds confusing, I hope I will be able to explain myself.

I'm building an ERC20 token, and I've imported [OpenZeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/) implementation for it, changing only the decimals function and setting a name & symbol.

Now, in another contract, I'm creating a scanning machine, and I'm trying to check the balance of a contract. What is the best way to use the `_transfer` function from OpenZeppelin's contract, without re-initiating it in my token contract (called EcoCoin), and then creating an instance for my token contract?

This is the contract I want to check the balance:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {Muni, MuniData} from "./Municipality.sol";

contract Machine is MuniData {
    // What will the machine do?
    /*  1. Exchange bottles for tokens
            a. Receive bottles from recycler
            b. Mint tokens
            c. Send tokens to recycler

        2. Redeem tokens for real value
            a. Receive tokens from shop
            b. Check for Real Money (RM) funds amount.
                i. If funds are available, send money to shop
                ii. If insufficient funds, withdraw from municipality real money (RM) wallet.
            c. Exchange tokens for money
            d. Send money to shop using a payment processor (venmo, cashapp, etc.); i.e. CashApp can generate a QR code to scan. [CashApp API](https://developers.cash.app/docs/api/welcome)
            e. Burn tokens
    */

    struct exchangeMachine {
        uint64 exMachineID;
        string exMachineZipCode; // Zip code of the Municipality, even if the machine is not in the same exact zip code of the municipality.
        address exMachineAddress; // Tokens wallet address.
        uint256 exMachineRMBalance; // Real Money (RM) balance of the machine.
    }

    // Array of all exchange machines using the exchangeMachine struct
    exchangeMachine[] public exchangeMachines;

    /**
     * @notice  Create a new exchange machine.
     * @dev     Address of machine should be created prior to calling this function.
     * @return  uint256  ID of the new exchange machine.
     */
    function createMachine(
        string memory _exZip,
        address _exAddress
    ) public muniOnly returns (uint256) {
        exchangeMachine memory newMachine = exchangeMachine({
            exMachineID: uint64(exchangeMachines.length),
            exMachineZipCode: _exZip,
            exMachineAddress: _exAddress,
            exMachineRMBalance: 0 // Should get the balance from the wallet's address.
        });
        exchangeMachines.push(newMachine);
        return newMachine.exMachineID;
    }
}
```

`exMachineRMBalance: 0` This is the line I'm referring to; I'd also like this contract to mint & burn tokens, and I think that re-stating functions and creating an instance is not a good practice.

This is the contract (important parts of it) that inherits the ERC20 contract, and deploys my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {ERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import {Muni, MuniData} from "./Municipality.sol";
import {Ownable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract EcoCoin is ERC20, MuniData, Ownable {
    using Muni for address;
    constructor() ERC20("EcoCoin", "ECC") {}

    function decimals() public pure override returns (uint8) {
        return 0; // No decimal places for the token; 2 tokens for a bottle, 10~ tokens equivalent to one usd.
    }

// This is an example of re-declaring the function from the ERC20 implementation;
// I've created this for every check I need, but it feels bad practice.

    function _burnTokens(
        address account,
        uint256 amount
    ) public muniOnly returns (bool) {
        _burn(account, amount); // Burn tokens
        return true;
    }
```

[This is my GitHub repo](https://github.com/ChefAharoni/EcoCoin) for reference, if anyone is interested in the whole code.
I'm using [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh) as my development toolchain if relevant.

Comment: Does this answer provide anything helpful for you: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/144869/120999?

Comment: Using approve(address spender, uint256 amount) function of the IERC20 token inheritants can allow the machine to act on the user's funds.

Comment: That's good, thank you!

I'll create an interface myself and then reference it via an instance.